# VLC player - Video lost in fullscreen

Tags: vlc

I consider vlc player to be the goto player (even though now im starting to like the native elementary OS video player). When i make it full screen some part of video is getting lost.

Answer (score 2):

Unmaximise the vlc window, then go to fullscreen.

Comment: amazing it works... thanks buddy; any idea why it wasn't working when it is in full window?

Comment: No idea. Maybe it will get solved in Juno.

Comment: yeah hopefully.. i guess our voice would be heard.. and moreover i seriously think a good alternative should be created for Microsoft office suite